# Matplotlib won't animate a function

Tags: numpy, animation, matplotlib, scipy, physics

I'm trying to make an animation of the following wavefunction:

[image: Wavefunction]

For some reason my code works for n=0 but then it doesn't for any other n. I checked the values of the function for various n, x and t and it seems to work fine but for some reason matplotlib isn't animating. Here's the code:

```
%matplotlib qt

import numpy as np
from sympy import hermite
from scipy.special import gamma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def psi(n, x, t):
    A = (np.pi ** -0.25) * (1 / np.sqrt((2 ** n) * gamma(n + 1)))
    E = n + 0.5
    f = A * hermite(n, x) * np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) * np.cos(E * t)
    return f


def animar(f, x0=0, xf=1, dx=0.01, t0=0, tf=1, dt=0.01, ym=-2, yM=2):
    nf = int((xf - x0) / dx + 1)
    nt = int((tf - t0) / dt + 1)
    x = np.linspace(x0, xf, nf)
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, nt)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.set_xlim((x0, xf))
    ax.set_ylim((ym, yM))

    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    def animate(i):
        y = f(x, i)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames=5 * t, interval=20, blit=True)
    plt.show()
    return anim


F = lambda x,t: psi(1, x, t)
anim = animar(F, x0=-3, xf=3, tf=3, ym=-1, yM=1)
```

Comment: Your function also works when you take `x` out and define it as `hermite(n, 1)`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to evaluate the hermite polynomials symbolically. Instead, why not use [`numpy.polynomial.hermite.hermval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.hermite.hermval.html#numpy.polynomial.hermite.hermval)?  Also maybe use [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html) to calculate the factorial.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import hermval
from scipy.special import factorial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def psi(n, x, t):
    A = (np.pi ** -0.25) * (1 / np.sqrt((2 ** n) * factorial(n)))
    E = n + 0.5
    nar = np.zeros(n+1)
    nar[-1] = 1
    f = A * hermval(x,nar) * np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) * np.cos(E * t)
    return f


def animar(f, x0=0, xf=1, dx=0.01, t0=0, tf=1, dt=0.01, ym=-2, yM=2):
    nf = int((xf - x0) / dx + 1)
    nt = int((tf - t0) / dt + 1)
    x = np.linspace(x0, xf, nf)
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, nt)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.set_xlim((x0, xf))
    ax.set_ylim((ym, yM))

    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    def animate(i):
        y = f(x, i)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames=5 * t, interval=20, blit=True)
    plt.show()
    return anim


F = lambda x,t: psi(3, x, t)
anim = animar(F, x0=-3, xf=3, tf=3, ym=-1, yM=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix. Redefine your `psi` function to be:

```
def psi(n, x, t):
    A = (np.pi ** -0.25) * (1 / np.sqrt((2 ** n) * gamma(n + 1)))
    E = n + 0.5
    herms = np.array([hermite(n, xelem) for xelem in x])
    f = A * herms * np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) * np.cos(E * t)
    return f
```

Basically, `hermite` seems to be a little weird/buggy. If `x` if a numpy array, then `hermite(n=0, x)` works just fine. However, if `n>0` then `hermite` will complain bitterly if `x` is anything other than a single value. So we work around that by feeding in the values from `x` to `hermite` one at a time, then make the `herms` array from those results.

Quantum mechanics was many years ago now, so I can't tell you if there is a justifiable reason for the inconsistency of `hermite` vis-a-vis array inputs. My guess is that it's just down to a slightly buggy implementation in `sympy`. In any case, once you fix up those two lines in `psi` the animations seem to work fine.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. It's weird because I could get hermite to work when making a regular plot in x and manually change the value of t, but not on the animation. But welp, thanks for the help.